# How to integrate facebook lead form with custom developed CRM using webhook

Tags: codeigniter

How to integrate facebook lead form  with custom developed CRM(codeigniter) using webhook

I need below lead field value in my crm..

[image]

Inside the function I wrote a code as below

```
 $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
  $verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

  if ($verify_token === 'abc123') {
  echo $challenge;
  }

  $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php:://input'), true);
  error_log(print_r($input, true));
  $file = "./assets/tmp/post_fb_test".time().".txt"; file_put_contents($file,$input); chmod($file, 0777);
```

Here i get a blank file..I don't get any value..Pls help me to integrate leadform with crm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_GET['hub_challenge']) {

       echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];

    } else {
                $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
                if($input)
                {
                    $input_data         = json_decode($input, true);
                    $file = "./assets/tmp/lead_test".time().".txt"; 
                    file_put_contents($file,$input); 
                    chmod($file, 0777);  
                }
  }
```